# Tableau MTTD calculation only shows one result

Tags: tableau-api

I'm calculating how long it takes to detect an issue in Tableau.
I have the following calculated field to work out mean time to detection:

```
DATEDIFF('hour',[DATE Reported], [DATE Responded])
```

When I use the meantimetodetect calculated field it only shows me one result and the rest 0s.

The one result shown is correct there were 3 days apart from when it was reported to the response date. The rest of the results are reported and responded in the same day so I dont know if that has anything to do with it?

Does anyone know why it is displaying like this perhaps there is a better way to calculate it?

Thanks.